# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/app/current/bootstrap/app.php:14

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2, error-handling, composer-php

I am trying to deploy a laravel application on my server.But when i am trying to access any `php artsan` commands, i am getting the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/app/current/bootstrap/app.php:14
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /var/app/current/artisan(20): require_once()
>
> #1 {main}
>
> thrown in /var/app/current/bootstrap/app.php on line 14

when i am searching for the solutions on internet, i ve been told to use the following **composer commands**:

> composer dump-autoload
>
> composer install --no-scripts

When i follow this commands, i get this error:

> 1 package you are using is looking for funding.
>
> Use the composer fund command to find out more!

Could anyone sort this ??
No security vulnerability advisories found
composer update --no-scripts

Comment: Try deleting your vendor directory and running `composer install` again

Comment: i have tried deleting vendor folder and compser installed..still same

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Maybe check what the vendor folder contains? Also, is this problem really related to EC2?

Comment: The message _"1 package you are using is looking for funding.
Use the composer fund command to find out more!"_ is **not** an error. It is just informative.